# Is there a way to copy my panning pattern from one audio file to another?

Tags: stereo, panning

I'm working in adobe audition and I have a very intricately designed panning patter for one of my tracks.  I could go brute force and do it on each track (about 3, so not too tragic, probably an hour of work), but it'd be really nice if I could somehow copy/save the keyframes/levels on one track... I don't think that it's possible, but you never know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Adobe Audition before, but I suppose, that you used automation. You should be able to copy automation from one track to another.

Second option could be duplicate the track (with automation) and replace audio.